# Safen User Input Part I - htmlspecialchars

Tags: python

You are a(n) novice/average/experienced/professional/world-famous Web Developer (choose one) who owns a(n) simple/clean/slick/beautiful/complicated/professional/business website (choose one or more) which contains form fields so visitors can send emails or leave a comment on your website with ease. However, with ease comes danger. Every now and then, a hacker visits your website and attempts to compromise it through the use of XSS (Cross Site Scripting). This is done by injecting script tags into the website through form fields which may contain malicious code (e.g. a redirection to a malicious website that steals personal information).

Mission
Your mission is to implement a function that converts the following potentially harmful characters:

< --> <

> --> >
> " --> "
> & --> &

My code is below :

```
def html_special_chars(data): 
    if "<" in data:
        return data.replace("<","&lt;")
    elif ">" in data:
        return data.replace(">","&gt;")
    elif '"' in data:
        return data.replace('"',"&quot;")
    else:
        return data.replace('&',"&amp;")
```

i got output for "alert('Website Hacked!' is <script>alert('Website Hacked! but it should be like this :"<script>alert('Website Hacked!');</script>"

Comment: Because you don't need if, elif, etc. here. You need to replace ALL the characters. Check your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution:

```py
def html_special_chars(data): 
    symbols = {'<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '"': '&quot;', '&': '&amp;'}
    return "".join(symbols.get(x, x) for x in data)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.